# How do I work on multiple appengine projects with python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I need to export my blobstore from one appengine project and upload it to another project. How can I switch between projects programmatically with python?

Answer (score 0):

If by "python" you mean a python GAE app's code itself - AFAIK you can't switch apps - each such code runs only inside the app specified in the `.yaml` file.

You could teach the exporting app project to serve the blob and for the actual transfer you could either:

- have the receving app directly pulling the blobs from the exporting app
- have an external (python) script pull blobs from the exporting apps and uploading them to the importing app.

Either way you'd need to write some code to actually perform the transfer.

So instead of doing that, I'd rather write and execute a one-time conversion script to  move the data from blobstore (presently shown in the [GAE python docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) under `Storing Data` > **`Superseded Storage Solutions`** section on the left-side menubar) to the Datastore or GCS, both of which have better backup/restore options, including across apps :) GCS can probably be even used to share the same data across apps. And you can still serve the GCS data using the blobstore API, see [Uploading files directly to Google Cloud Storage for GAE app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225000/uploading-files-directly-to-google-cloud-storage-for-gae-app/37227087#37227087)

If you mean some external python app code - AFAIK the blobstore doesn't offer generic access directly to an external application (I *might* be wrong, tho). So an external app would need to go through the regular upload/download handlers of the 2 apps. So in this case switching between projects really means switching between the 2 apps' upload/download URLs.

Even for this scenario it  might be worthy to migrate to GCS, which does offer direct access, see [Sharing and Collaboration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration)

Comment: I mean some external python code, something like a django command for appengine that would be able to switch between projects and could then read from one blobstore and write to the other.