# How to upload Photo to backend asynchronously from webpage and receive URL using GCS

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, webapp2, blobstore

My tech stack is Angularjs, python, webapp2, and AppEngine. I've had immense difficulty in figuring out how to do this. The documentation from Google is very poor. I either want to use blob store or use GCS. I have more preference for the latter as it seems to have a free tier.

Comment: These may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225000/uploading-files-directly-to-google-cloud-storage-for-gae-app/37227087#37227087, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972477/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-file-by-url-to-cloud-storage-on-app-engine-without-wr/32973871#32973871

Comment: Hello Vivek RC, did @DanCornilescu answer worked for you?